# Video streaming time detection

Tags: streaming

I want to stream a small piece of sound or a video. For this example lets saty a song. But I would like to know how much of the song the user heard. By this I mean; did she listen to the end? or stopped playback after 30 seconds.

At the moment I am in the research phase, so format and different ways are up for proposal.

I tried splitten the track up in 10 parts, creating a playlist with 10 parts and then creating a link to that playlist. But this seems to not work on most players.

Then I was thinking about placing active elements in the track. Like using mp4 or similar to make HTTP requests (or something else) to my server. But I dont think that is possible.

Anybody have any idear how to solve this? I don't even know where to search on Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: in a web-based environment you can track user actions. Many web players provide callbacks like onPlay, onPause, onResume, onStop.

Server-side, for a stream served directly to different devices, you could switch to a HTTP streaming protocol like HLS and keep track of sessions. This will tell you how many packets the client has received, not necessarily played.

Using intermmediate caching servers / a CDN renders this solution useless however.